# how do i create a username and password system that remembers different usernames everytime i use the code?

Tags: python, python-3.4

i need to create a music quiz game but only authorised players are allowed to play the game so i figured id create a username and password system but how do i do this please?

so far i have this:

```
name = input("Please enter your name. ")
age = input("Now please enter you age. ")

username = name[0:3] + age
print ("Your username has been created and 
is", username, ".")

password = input("Now please create a 
password. ")

file = open("Login.txt","a")
file.write (username)
file.write (",")
file.write (password)
file.write("\n")
file.close()

print ("Your login details have been saved")
```

it saves the username and passwords created but how do I create a system so that the user can just enter their username and password after this from the stored usernames and passwords?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionnary for doing it.

```
import json

create_user():
    global users
    name = input("Please enter your name. ")
    age = input("Now please enter you age. ")

    username = name[0:3] + age
    print ("Your username has been created and is", username, ".")

    password = input("Now please create a  password.")
    users[username] = password
    with open ("Login.txt", 'w') as fd:
        json.dump(users, fd)
    print("Your login details have been saved")

load_users():
    try:
        with open("Login.txt", 'r') as fd:
            users = json.load(fd)
    except:
        print("can't load Login.txt, default dict used")
        users = {}

login():
    username = input("username >")
    password = input("password >")
    if username in users.keys() and password == users[username]:
        print("logged as", username)
        return username
    else
        print("login failed")
        return None
users = load_users()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions flat out:

- Ask for the password twice at the time of creation; saves the pain of dealing with typos
- Use getpass.getpass() for inputting passwords
- Don't store passwords in a file. If databases are too much of a hassle, use one-way hash functions.

Now, assuming you'd still like to continue without a database, an easier way to do this might be to store username-password pairs in a dictionary format in [say] a pickle object. Every time you ask somebody to log in, ask for a username, check for the presence of the username in the dictionary keys. If you find the key, ask for the password, and match it with the value corresponding to the key.

```
from getpass import getpass
import os, pickle, hashlib
userdata = dict()
if os.path.exists('userinfo.pickle'):
    userdata = pickle.load(open('userinfo.pickle','rb'))
username = raw_input("Enter username:")
pwd = getpass("Enter password:")
pwd2 = getpass("Enter password again:")
if pwd != pwd2:
    exit(0)
h = hashlib.md5()
h.update(pwd)
pwd = h.hexdigest()
if username not in userdata:
    userdata[username] = pwd
with open('userinfo.pickle','wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(userdata,handle)

# Logging in
userdata = pickle.load(open('userinfo.pickle','rb'))
username = raw_input("Enter username:")
pwd = getpass("Enter password:")
h = hashlib.md5()
h.update(pwd)
pwd = h.hexdigest()
if username in userdata:
    if userdata[username] == pwd:
        print("Success.")
    else:
        print("Incorrect password.")
else:
    print("User not found.")
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using a CSV to separate your names and usernames, this would make it much easier to search for a username and password pair. If you would want to use this, the following should work:

Creating username/password:

```
import pandas as pd

userpass = pd.read_csv('Login.csv')
name = input("Please enter your name. ")
age = input("Now please enter you age. ")

username = name[0:3] + age
print ("Your username has been created and 
is", username, ".")

password = input("Now please create a 
password. ")

newuserpass = [(username, password)]
newuserpass = pd.DataFrame(newuserpass) #Creates a dataframe of username & pass
userpass = userpass.append(newuserpass) #Adds username and pass dataframe to end of username/password save file
userpass.to_csv('Login.csv')
'''This has now saved the login details. Now to read the login details, where pandas makes this quite easy'''
```

Loading username/password:

```
loggedin = 0
while loggedin = 0:
    userpass = pd.read_csv('Login.csv')
    inputusername = input('What is your username?')
    inputpassword = input('What is your password?')




    if userpass.Password.values[userpass.Username==inputusername] == inputpassword:
      userpass = 1
      print('Logged in successfully!')
```

You will need to create a blank file named 'Login.csv' with Username, Password as its contents before this code would function.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it says 'no module names pandas'. help. ive created the blank file btw

Comment: Ah. You don't have Pandas installed. No worries, take a look at this link to get it. Pandas is a very useful library for data handling. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html

Comment: i cant install it! im doing this in school :(

Comment: Ah. That is a shame. This answer requires pandas - I'm surprised that your school doesn't have it. You will need to check if you can use 'import' to import any of the libraries in the other answers here. Best of luck.